# Creating generic ajax-search in AngularJS (Directive, Service?)

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I'm looking to build an Ajax search bar that could be re-used to search different parts of the site.

I'm thinking that as for the generic way that it takes input and displays an output, a directive would be good for this but I want to hook on different search mechanisms depending on where it's used.

Since I would want to hook on different search functionality whenever I wanted, a service for each functionality is what I have in mind but I'm wondering if it's possible to tell a directive which service to use? Or, what the best way to approach this would be.

Answer (score 1):

I guess a combination of a service and a controller, let the directive accept a search function (like ngclick) and the controller will link the service to the scope so you can bind it.  That way the directive will be pretty dumb, and yet able to accept getters from any service.

Sorry for the lack of code, typing from mobile.